# how to customize angucomplete-alt template for people search?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

In my application form, I implemented autocomplete drop down by using angucomplete-alt(search people example) directive. here is the link [click here see example 2](http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/) It is like search field on twitter. I am getting output exactly like twitter user search but missing the verified account blue tick actually I have the data for verified or not but not getting how to customize the angucomplete-alt template I am using angularjs 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<div angucomplete-alt
  id="ex14"
  placeholder="Search countries"
  pause="100"
  selected-object="countrySelected14"
  local-data="countries"
  search-fields="name"
  title-field="name"
  minlength="1"
  input-class="form-control form-control-small"
  match-class="highlight"
  template-url="/my-custom-template.html">
</div>
```

Define your custom template like this:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/my-custom-template.html">
   <div class="angucomplete-holder" ng-class="{'angucomplete-dropdown-visible': showDropdown}">
    <p>This is custom</p>
     <input ng-model="searchStr"
       ng-disabled="disableInput"
       type="text"
       placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
       ng-focus="onFocusHandler()"
       class="{{inputClass}}"
       ng-focus="resetHideResults()"
       ng-blur="hideResults($event)"
       autocapitalize="off"
       autocorrect="off"
       autocomplete="off"
       ng-change="inputChangeHandler(searchStr)"/>
     <div class="angucomplete-dropdown" ng-show="showDropdown">
       <div class="angucomplete-searching" ng-show="searching" ng-bind="textSearching"></div>
       <div class="angucomplete-searching" ng-show="!searching && (!results || results.length == 0)" ng-bind="textNoResults"></div>
       <div class="angucomplete-row" ng-repeat="result in results" ng-click="selectResult(result)" ng-mouseenter="hoverRow($index)" ng-class="{'angucomplete-selected-row': $index == currentIndex}">
         <div ng-if="imageField" class="angucomplete-image-holder">
           <img ng-if="result.image && result.image != ''" ng-src="{{result.image}}" class="angucomplete-image"/>
           <div ng-if="!result.image && result.image != ''" class="angucomplete-image-default"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="angucomplete-title" ng-if="matchClass" ng-bind-html="result.title"></div>
         <div class="angucomplete-title" ng-if="!matchClass">{{ result.title }}</div>
         <div ng-if="matchClass && result.description && result.description != ''" class="angucomplete-description" ng-bind-html="result.description"></div>
         <div ng-if="!matchClass && result.description && result.description != ''" class="angucomplete-description">{{result.description}}</div>
       </div>
       <div class="angucomplete-row" ng-click="selectResult({title: searchStr, originalObject: { name: searchStr, custom: true }})" ng-mouseenter="hoverRow(results.length)" ng-class="{'angucomplete-selected-row': results.length == currentIndex}">
         <div class="angucomplete-title">Select custom country '{{ searchStr }}'</div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</script>
```

Code from this link: [angucomplete-alt](http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/)